# How to send custom string with QBRTCSession object

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode6, quickblox

In my application I have implemented quickblox SDK for voice and video call and everything is working perfectly. There is just one issue which I am facing. To track the particular call in background I have a session created between two users. But while making this call I want to send the same session Id to the opponent also. If somebody could help me please tell me how could i do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Got the solution!!

Refer http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-ios

Before making a call I have following line of code written in my file

```
[self.session startCall:userInfo];
```

Here you can write anything inside userInfo dictionary. As soon as opponent receives the call

```
- (void)didReceiveNewSession:(QBRTCSession *)session userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

will be called. Here whatever you have written inside userInfo, you can read it directly.

```
[QBRTCClient.instance addDelegate:self];

// 2123, 2123, 3122 - opponent's
NSArray *opponentsIDs = @[@3245, @2123, @3122];
QBRTCSession *newSession = [QBRTCClient.instance    createNewSessionWithOpponents:opponentsIDs
                                                         withConferenceType:QBConferenceTypeVideo];
// userInfo - the custom user information dictionary for the call. May be nil.
NSDictionary *userInfo = @{ @"key" : @"value" };
[newSession startCall:userInfo];
```

Start call method definition says the same

```
/**
 *  Start call. Opponent will receive new session signal in     QBRTCClientDelegate method 'didReceiveNewSession:userInfo:
 *
 * @param userInfo The user information dictionary for the stat call. May be nil.
 */
- (void)startCall:(NSDictionary *)userInfo;
```